# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string in Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, ora-01830

I'm trying to fix and error in a XML script to make a concurrent in Oracle EBS, but i'm not having success. I need to convert a parameter 'type=date 'to "dd/MM/yyyy", but everything i try, nothing works. This error is persisting everytime.

My parameter is "parameter name="P_DATA"  dataType="date""

My select is  "SELECT To_char(:P_DATA, 'dd/MM/yyyy') C_DATA
              FROM DUAL"

Please, someone help me to fix this. Thankss

Comment: Please show us some sample data.  All it would take is one bad record to cause this.

Comment: What's in `:p_data`?